# Get the list of Employees in which 3 or more than 3 employees are from same city?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, group-by

I am using the below query to find the City Name having More than 3 Employees

```
SELECT M.NAME
FROM MasterCity M
INNER JOIN Employee E ON E.CityID = M.ID
GROUP BY E.CityID
HAVING count(E.CityID) >= 3;
```

It gives me the following error

```
Column 'MasterCity.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

What is wrong.? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variant #1 -

```
SELECT MAX(M.Name) AS Name
FROM MasterCity M 
JOIN Employee E ON E.CityID = M.ID
GROUP BY E.CityID
HAVING COUNT(E.CityID) >= 3;
```

Variant #2 -

```
SELECT M.Name
FROM MasterCity M 
JOIN Employee E ON E.CityID = M.ID
GROUP BY E.CityID, M.Name
HAVING COUNT(E.CityID) >= 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT M.ID, M.Name 
FROM MasterCity M 
INNER JOIN Employee E ON E.CityID = M.ID
GROUP BY M.ID, M.Name 
HAVING COUNT(E.CityID) >= 3;
```